# Is there a way to disable swipe events in KendoUI Mobile's ScrollView?

Tags: jquery, cordova, scrollview, kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI Mobile's [ScrollView](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/scrollview) control as a carousel to house some questions and need to disable swipe events for it (I'm using "next" and "previous" buttons to control the "navigation").

The problem I'm coming across is that I have a [jQuery-UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) inside the ScrollView, but when I try to change the slider value, it starts to move the ScrollView to the next "page".

I was hoping there was a native way to disable "swipe to move" on the ScrollView, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

I've played around with catching the events on the ScrollView pages, but haven't been able to get something that works on an actual device:

```
$('#scrollview-container [data-role="page"]').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    console.log('mousedown');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$('#scrollview-container [data-role="page"]').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    console.log('touchstart');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

The above works in my simulator, but not on an actual device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also using Next and PRevious buttons instead of the swipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered here: [http://www.telerik.com/forums/scrollview-is-missing-a-lot-of-essential-functionality-(-)](http://www.telerik.com/forums/scrollview-is-missing-a-lot-of-essential-functionality-%28-%29)

```
var scrollview = $("[data-role=scrollview]").getKendoMobileScrollView();
var cancel = function() { this.cancel(); };

scrollview.pane.userEvents.bind("start", cancel); //disable the pages movement

// to no-longer disable the swipe use this:
// scrollview.pane.userEvents.unbind("start", cancel); //enable the pages movement
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the event blocking right, you'll need to look at exactly how and when the binding is done when setting up the swipe event. on(), bind() and live() produce different event orders, and it won't help if you block the event after it has already started a swipe.

Blocking the event on a child element may work better though, as order relative to the event set up by the framework doesn't matter. Try stopping propagation of touch events from the immediate parent of the slider.